# NavBar in home screen not appearing after sign in

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm making an app that requires login, so if you are not logged in, it redirects to the login screen, and after log in, it doesn't display the whole "Home Screen" Completely. It is missing the nav bar. If you close the app and open it again, the navBar is there.

Do you guys know why? Any help is appreciate it.

I'm using 2 different navigation controllers. 1 for the login and sign up, another for the home screen and the rest of the app.

If I'm not logged in, I'm redirected to the login screen with:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){
        performSegueWithIdentifier("notSignedIn", sender: self)
    }
}
```

and it goes to the login screen with no issues. After logged in, I tried this two different method and both do not display the navigation bar after redirected to home screen:

**Method 1**

```
if (user != nil) {
    let homeScreen = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeScreen") as! TimelineTableViewController

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(homeScreen, animated: true)
}
```

**Method 2**
After login I redirect back to the screen that lets you login or sign up with:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

and once you are in the I use the same with a siege to go back to Home Screen, but either way it doesn't display the navigation bar in the Home screen.

Comment: Show your code like how you redirects to the login screen?

Comment: Have you used push Home screen after login success? and navigation controller in home screen?

Comment: I just posted the code I'm using for redirect.

Comment: @AvijitNagare what do you mean?

Comment: can you show screen shot of your storyboard?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I cannot post photos until I get 10 rep /:

Comment: @whereisleo figured it out. I forgot I was using `navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = Bool` in a different VC

Comment: your viewWillAppear method will call multiple time. better you can use this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629540/in-which-method-should-i-check-for-nsuserdefaults/31629621#31629621

Comment: @AvijitNagare Yes I have an auto-login function, so it doesn't go to the log in screen every time.

Comment: That code will do same as login success and save login user id in NSUserDefaults. then you don't need to hide and show navigation bar.

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used:

```
  navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = Bool
```

If it's not appearing in your VC screen use:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept it as an answer! :)

Comment: This worked!!! And yes in the login screen I had it hidden, so I'm guessing it carry to this view as well. I didn't think of this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did! But My upvotes do not show up until I'm rep 15 haha